# Multiple .NET Core service instances on Docker, AddHostedService issues

Tags: c#, docker, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-hosted-services

I'm running .NET Core 5.0 services on Docker, sometimes with multiple instances of the same service.

Some of the services have "Hosted Services" registered in their `Startup.cs` file.

However, I don't want these background services to run on more than one instance.

How can I handle this so that only 1 instance of the service will run the background services?

Comment: just explore this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.dependencyinjection.servicecollectionserviceextensions.addsingleton?view=dotnet-plat-ext-6.0

Comment: @viveknuna That won't solve this problem since they are different instances of the application that starts the hosted service.

Comment: @viveknuna as the above comment mentioned, Singleton services will run 1 instance on each service instance so the problem will persist.

Comment: Explore if you can split your app into two, if they shouldn't scale at the same rate.

Comment: I don't quite understand your point @HansKilian, Can you elaborate?

Comment: If you have one part of your app that you want to scale by adding multiple instances of it and another that you don't want to scale at the same rate, then the best solution might be to split them into two, so you can have multiple containers of one part and a single container of the second.

Comment: @TheZingerator could you fix the issue?
We created a unique instance for the application running the hosted service in EC2 and turned off the hosted service for the other instances that may scale.